# Subtracting hex-valued file names

Tags: hex, qnx, difference

Using QNX Neutrino, I need to subtract hex-valued file names from their predecessors. The files are named by their creation time in hex. The following gets me a list of pure hex values, but I cannot subtrace them from eachother.

```
last=0
find /path/ -type f\(! iname ".*" \) -exec basename {} |
while read fname
do
    current=$fname
    echo "difference is $((current - last)) seconds
done
```

The find command gives me:

```
51b71f38
51b71f44
51b71f50
51b71f5c
51b71f74
```

I have tried using echo "ibase=16; $name" | bc but that only switches the value for the output.  Is there a way to return an integer number which is the difference for these hex values?

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this:

```
find /path/ -type f\(! iname ".*" \) -exec basename {} |
while read fname; do 
    last="$current"
    current="$fname"
    if [ $(( 0x$last )) -ne 0 ]; then  
        echo "difference is $(( 0x$current - 0x$last )) seconds"
    fi
done
```

#### Test:

I used your find command as input from a file for the test.

```
$ cat ff
51b71f38
51b71f44
51b71f50
51b71f5c
51b71f74

$ while read fname; do last="$current" ; current="$fname" ; if [ $(( 0x$last )) -ne 0 ]; then  echo "difference is $(( 0x$current - 0x$last )) seconds" ; fi ; done < ff
difference is 12 seconds
difference is 12 seconds
difference is 12 seconds
difference is 24 seconds
```

Comment: Jaypal, I tried inserting 0x infront of the variables and ran into problems as well.  I found a way to convert the hex numbersinline with the variable declaration as seen above.

Comment: Hmm, if you want to discuss the issue then let me know. But good to head that you were able to get it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
current=$(echo "ibase=16; $fname" |bc)
```

actually gives me the decimal value I needed inline